# What are the pros and cons of this different approach to registering users?

Tags: registration

I came across a website recently that presented me with the following:

[image]

Password appears after you start filling In

[image]

This felt like a very idiot-proof, fun and novel approach.
Am I missing some kind of glaring flaw here?

Comment: Natural language works for some, more informal websites, but on many others a sign up form like the one above could be considered superfluous and childish.

Answer (score 2):

**Pros:**

- It helps build a community by telling you immediately how many other users  there are and that you're joining them.
- As you said its fairly idiot proof, it reads in natural language so its easier to understand.
- Comes across as friendly and personal, like you're speaking straight to the user.
- Can look "fun" so users may sign up just to play with that type of form.

**Cons:**

- Non-english readers will have no idea what the sentences are telling  them and may avoid the form, you may have to translate this yourself for internationalization.
- Unfamiliar to users who are very familiar with standard registration may be confused.
- More wordy, some people may see that block of text and not want to read it so they skip it (if possible)
- When that much text is shown on smaller devices such as mobile phone screens. those 3 sentences may look a lot more like a paragraph after wrapping and may even require scrolling to see it all
- After wrapping the inputs might not make as much sense. If the lead up is "I am" and then the input is on another line it may be confusing, make sure to keep placeholders.
- Harder to fit validation/error messages (especially instant validation) around the input boxes since it's surrounded by text.

EDIT: If you do decide to go for it here is a little plugin that allows different types of input such as dropdowns a lookups: [Natural Language Form](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/05/21/natural-language-form-with-custom-input-elements/)

But be weary, that introduces a whole other set of pros/cons.

Answer (score 1):

This works very well for the type of site where it is ok to have multiple Daves. I like the informal aspect.
Downsides may be: in this privacy-wary time, it may be off putting that you don't say what their email is for. When they come to log on for the first time, they may be unsure what their username is. That said, I still like the approach for this site.